# Vim regex match bar following foo

Tags: regex, vim

In vim regex:

If `/foo\(bar\)\@=/` matches `foo` followed by `bar`
Then what matches `bar` following `foo`?

I tried `/\(foo\)\@=bar/` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
\(foo\)\@<=\(bar\)
```

You should use positive **lookbehind**(instead of lookahead) operator, because you're trying to match bar, *preceeded* by foo.

BTW, here is the link, which I always use as a [cheatsheet for vim regex operators](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/vim/searching.html)

Answer (score 5):

These are easier way in `Vim`. You can use `\zs`(match start) and `\ze`(match end).

#### match `foo` followed by `bar`

```
foo\zebar
```

#### match `bar` following `foo`

```
foo\zsbar
```